# Swift: creating UI when function is called

Tags: ios, swift, view

I've got one of these Views here:

```
let placeContainerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true

    return view
}()
```

And I'm looking to create one next to it every time a function "createNewView()" is called.

```
    let showFullPlaceContainerView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showFullPlaceContainerViewFunction))
    placeContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(showFullPlaceContainerView)
```

That I want each of the placeContainerView's to respond to.

So I want a view to be generated and I'll give it certain values. And then when I call the function createNewView() I'll get a new view next to it that is exactly the same except with whatever new values I put in.

If you've got any ideas please let me know!

Thank you

EDIT:

The code below demonstrates how I want to setup the placeContainerView each time but I need them to be displayed so that the placeContainerView.topAnchor() is different each time.. How exactly does that work if it is kept in its own class and doesn't know how many times it has been created?

Also, as placeContainerView contains placeLabel and placeImageView do these have to be generated inside the new PlaceContainerViewClass as well?

```
func setupPlaceContainerView() {
    placeContainerView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor, constant: -180).active = true
    placeContainerView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 80).active = true
    placeContainerView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(227).active = true
    placeContainerView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(45).active = true


    placeContainerView.addSubview(placeLabel)
    placeContainerView.addSubview(placeImageLabelSeparator)
    placeContainerView.addSubview(placeImageView)

    placeLabel.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(placeContainerView.leftAnchor).active = true
    placeLabel.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(placeContainerView.topAnchor).active = true
    placeLabel.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(180).active = true
    placeLabel.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(placeContainerView.heightAnchor).active = true

    placeImageLabelSeparator.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(placeLabel.rightAnchor).active = true
    placeImageLabelSeparator.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(placeContainerView.topAnchor).active = true
    placeImageLabelSeparator.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(2).active = true
    placeImageLabelSeparator.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(placeContainerView.heightAnchor).active = true

    placeImageView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(placeImageLabelSeparator.rightAnchor).active = true
    placeImageView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(placeContainerView.topAnchor).active = true
    placeImageView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(45).active = true
    placeImageView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(placeContainerView.heightAnchor).active = true
```

Comment: First, create a subclass of UIView rather than just a computed property. Then you can pass an appropriate `CGRect` to the subclass's `init(frame:)` Initializer when you need an instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @Paulw11, this task is simply done by creating a new class.

```
class placeContainerView:UIView {

    var x:Double!
    var y:Bool!
    var z:UILabel!
    var controller:UIViewController!

    //If you want to pass specific values number, you can use convenience init method OR you can use the default init method they give you.
    //previousLabelFrame:CGrect = CGRect() // I defaulted all these values to 0, make them whatevree u need. You would use the default one for the first Label you would make. Then after that, you would pass in the previous one made, to get the frame of it so you can add to the one after that. 
    convenience init(x:Double,y:Bool, z:UILabel, previousLabelFrame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width:0, height:0), VC:UIViewController) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.controller = VC
        let distance = self.controller.width*0.1 //Whatever u decide here
        //You could just do CGRect(x:previousLabelFrame.maxX+distance, depeding on what you need. 
        self.frame = CGRect(x: previousLabelFrame.minX+distance, y:previousLabelFrame.minY, width: previousLabelFrame.width, height:previousLabelFrame.height)
    }

}
```

Usage inside ViewController:

```
var views:[placeContainerView] = []

let view:placeContainerView = placeContainerView(10, true, UILabel(),views[views.count-1], self)
 self.views.append(view)
//OR if this is the FIRST placeContainerView of the whole app, it will use the default values for the frame.
let view:placeContainerView = placeContainerView(10, true, UILabel(), self)
self.views.append(view)
```

Some odd example of how to use. 
Then everytime they click a button, just make a new placeContainerView

Comment: I get you. I've added some extra information to the original post to highlight some of my further confusion.

Comment: When does the func createNewView get called? Thatll help me explain this

Comment: createNewView() will be called when the user types something into a search bar. The placeContainerView has a UILabel which then displays what has been typed into the search bar. It's just a way of recording someone's searches.

Comment: Do you want to replace the OLD placecontainerview or a NEW one next to it? If you want a new one, you need to keep up with the frame with the old one.

Comment: I'm trying to create a new one next to it. Understood but doesn't that mean I have to keep track of how many there are? I'm not sure how to recode the setupPlaceContainerView so it's relevant to all generated placeContainers.

Comment: Haha, do you ever remove old ones? Or you only need the MOST RECENT 1?

Comment: The old ones should get removed when a different button is pressed lol but I haven't really gotten that far yet. Normally I'd want them to swipe to delete..